# Issue on Deducting Current Time From Default Time

Tags: javascript

I have a simple time calculation code like below and I would like to get remaining time from now to default time `app`

```js
var app = "16:30";
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();
var res = app - time;
console.log(res);
```

Can you please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man - if only this kind of math worked on strings! You're trying to subtract one string from another, and as a result it's unclear what should happen. Try something like this instead:

```
var appDate = new Date();
appDate.setHours(16);
appDate.setMinutes(30);
appDate.setSeconds(0);
appDate.setMilliseconds(0);

alert(appDate);

var now = new Date();

alert(now);

var diff = appDate.getTime() - now.getTime();

alert(diff + " milliseconds remaining.");
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7c70eu64/)

Comment: or `appDate.setHours(16,30,0,0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't subtract strings, you should work with dates.

You could convert the strings to dates though.

```js
var dateStr = "16:30"
var app = new Date();
var tmp = dateStr.split(":");
app.setHours(tmp[0],tmp[1]);

var time = new Date();
var res = (new Date(time - app)+'').split(" ")[4];
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `new Date(app - time);` ? Why not `Math.abs(time.getTime()-app.getTime())`

Comment: It gives me a date in 1969 `"1969-12-31T19:56:00.000Z"` instead of a number of minutes or other useful stuff. Also your split was not JavaScript

Comment: @mpl The first is a legit remark, the second - what? It is javascript...

Comment: split\`:\`[0] is not a dialect of JS I have seen yet. Perhaps ES6 or something?

Comment: It actually does. Apologies. Disgusting syntax. I rolled back

Comment: Yes, better except for that dreadful split\`:\` which is neither useful not educative nor clever. Why on earth did you use it?

Comment: @mpl You mean, the original syntax is beautiful and better use it? I've learned this one on codegolf SE.

Comment: It is not supported by a million of browsers and is not understandable by anyone not on ES6 who also understands your hacky use of it. So it is objectionable and ugly and poor coding practice. I can't even easily find documentation for the use of your syntax. Here is the split supported by all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: @mpl Fair enough, removed those artifacts :D